# is it possible to instatiate abstract class providing the rest of the implementation in place?

Tags: c#, java

Having such class can I instatiate it in place?

```
abstract class Mammal {
    public abstract void Foo();
}
```

I expect that something like that should work:

```
Mammal wolf = new Mammal() {
    public void Foo() { Console.WriteLine("Wooo"); }
}
```

However compilier doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're after something akin to an anonymous inner class in Java. There's no equivalent in C#. Options:

- Create a nested class instead.
- Create an implementation which uses delegates for each of the abstract methods, and then use anonymous functions to create those implementations "inline"
- If the type consists of just a single abstract method, *consider* using a delegate instead of the abstract class to start with.

Comment: Thanks Jon as always! If class is NOT abstract and I just want to override existent method in place I still have same choice? (default implementation of method doesn't do anything but client may override when needed).

Comment: @javapowered: Pretty much, yes. Basically there's nothing directly like an anonymous inner class in C#.

Answer (score 1):

The very definition of abstract class is a class that cannot be instantiated. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Use the abstract modifier in a class declaration to indicate that a
>   class is intended only to be a base class of other classes. Members
>   marked as abstract, or included in an abstract class, must be
>   implemented by classes that derive from the abstract class.

Having said that, it can have a constructor.

Your code <s>does not make a lot of sense</s> does not work in C#.

Comment: The code makes perfect sense to a Java programmer, where you can do exactly that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I remember now. I have done some Java - you can implement interfaces in-situ.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it.
[See this reff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

But you can inherit you own class:

```
public class ConcreetMammal : Mammal 
{
       public void Foo() {Console.WriteLine("Wooo");}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this the closest I think you can get is to make `Foo` an `Action` and give `Mammal` a constructor that assigns a passed in function to `Foo`.

```
class Mammal {
    public readonly Action Foo;

    public Mammal(Action foo) { Foo = foo;}
}
...
...
var MyMammal = new Mammal(() => {Console.WriteLine("Wooo");});
```

Comment: i've changed `bool Foo` to `void Foo`

Comment: it's inconvinient. Actually I have 4 methods that may or may not be overriden (default implementation doesn't do anything), so I have to create 2^4 = 16 constructors....

Comment: Use optional parameters passing an empty method if it's not used (so just one constructor).

Comment: Then inheritance as suggested by Jon is probably what you should go for. I tried to answer, getting you as close to what you asked for as possible. :)

Comment: Note that the calling code would be shorter than your example in your question though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what Skeet was telling could be along these lines (great input as always)...

```
class Test
{
    public delegate void MyFooSig();

    public MyFooSig Foo { get; set; }
}

class Test1
{
    public Action Foo { get; set; }
    public Func<string, int, Test> MyOtherFoo { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test
        {
            Foo = () => Console.Write("I'm in Foo"),
        };

        test.Foo();

        var test1 = new Test1
        {
            Foo = () => Console.WriteLine("Foo via Action delegates"),
            MyOtherFoo = (s, i) => new Test 
            { 
                Foo = () => Console.WriteLine("here it's me again..."),
            },
        };
        test1.Foo();
        test1.MyOtherFoo("", 1).Foo();
    }
}
```

...not the same things though...
(note that's not inheritance, class is not abstract, it's more instantiating of one and the same)
plus there are dynamic objects - and you might want to take a look at Mock for C# for some ideas